# json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 305 column 2

Tags: json, python-3.x

i am using python 3 and while generating reports using behave2cucmber module getting this error while parsing json file using json module . 
observing awkward behavior also :   for 1  json file (file2.json) but for other file (reports.json) it working perfectly.

where is the problem ?

code :

```
import os
import behave2cucumber


infile = os.getcwd() +"/reports/report.json"
cucumber_output= None
with open(infile) as f:
    try:
        cucumber_output = behave2cucumber.convert(json.load(f), remove_background=False, 
        duration_format=False)
    except Exception:
        traceback.print_exc()
```

error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "features\environment.py", line 51, in after_all
    cucumber_output = behave2cucumber.convert(json.load(f), remove_background=False, duration_format=False)
  File "c:\users\pradeep.c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "c:\users\pradeep.c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\pradeep.c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\pradeep.c\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 305 column 2 (char 11544)
```

file >> report.json

```
 [
    {
        "keyword": "Feature",
        "name": "Login",
        "tags": [],
        "location": "features/test.feature:1",
        "status": "passed",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "scenario",
                "keyword": "Scenario",
                "name": "successfull of facebook webpage",
                "tags": [],
                "location": "features/test.feature:2",
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user launch browser",
                        "location": "features/test.feature:3",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/testing.py:6",
                            "arguments": []
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "passed",
                            "duration": 0.001966238021850586
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "open url https://www.facebook.com",
                        "location": "features/test.feature:4",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/testing.py:13",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "value": "https://www.facebook.com",
                                    "name": "url"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "passed",
                            "duration": 3.918867826461792
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "login page should be available",
                        "location": "features/test.feature:5",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/testing.py:18",
                            "arguments": []
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "passed",
                            "duration": 2.2839267253875732
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "status": "passed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

file >>   file2.json

```
    [
    {
        "keyword": "Feature",
        "name": "Pallet Pick Put",
        "tags": [],
        "location": "features/PPP.feature:1",
        "status": "failed",
        "elements": [
            {
                "type": "scenario",
                "keyword": "Scenario Outline",
                "name": "happy path Put flow -- @1.1 data",
                "tags": [],
                "location": "features/PPP.feature:40",
                "steps": [
                    {
                        "keyword": "Given",
                        "step_type": "given",
                        "name": "Setup is ready",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:3",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/ppp.py:8",
                            "arguments": []
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "passed",
                            "duration": 0.0009968280792236328
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user create put service request with serviceID sid_001 and lpn value b001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:4",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/ppp.py:12",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "value": "sid_001",
                                    "name": "service_id"
                                },
                                {
                                    "value": "b001",
                                    "name": "barcode"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "passed",
                            "duration": 0.0
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to <rack_location>",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:5",
                        "match": {
                            "location": "features/steps/ppp.py:99",
                            "arguments": [
                                {
                                    "value": "<rack_location>",
                                    "name": "waiting_barcode"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "result": {
                            "status": "failed",
                            "duration": 7.785275220870972,
                            "error_message": "Assertion Failed: butler not moved"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you reaches <rack_location>",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:6"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you will pick up rack",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:7"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to 519.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:8"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you reaches 519.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:9"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "tower light should turn \"red\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:10"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to 520.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:11"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you reaches 520.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:12"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will put down rack at ppp",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:13"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to 519.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:14"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you reaches 519.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "tower light should turn \"green\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:16"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user open \"http://192.168.9.49:3000\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:17"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "page with element \"username\" should get open",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:18"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user enters \"kaveesh\" and \"kaveesh\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:19"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user click \"login\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:20"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "page with element \"put loaded pallet\" should get open",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:21"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user click \"put loaded pallet\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:22"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "page with element \"scan lpn\" should get open",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:23"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user enters \"lpn value\" in the lpn text box",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:24"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user click \"submit\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:25"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "page with element \"stack\" should get open",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:26"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user enter \"row\" \"column\" \"stack\" values",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:27"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user press enter",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:28"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "page with element \"scan Mpu\" should get open",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:29"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user enter \"MPU value\" in the box",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:30"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "user click \"submit\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:31"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "tower light should turn \"red\"",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:32"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to 520.001",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:33"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "When",
                        "step_type": "when",
                        "name": "you reaches <your_barcode>",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:34"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "Then",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will pick up rack",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:35"
                    },
                    {
                        "keyword": "And",
                        "step_type": "then",
                        "name": "you will move to storable location",
                        "location": "features/PPP.feature:36"
                    }
                ],
                "status": "failed"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```